# Regex match from pound symbol to end of line

Tags: java, regex

I've tried to use regexr.com to come up with a solution, but I can't find one. I'm looking for some Regex that will match this:

```
#This is some text \n
```

Where I would like to match that **entire** line, where it starts at the pound symbol and ends at the new line character. For example:

```
#This is some text \n
This is some text I don't want to match
```

I would like to match the first line so I can completely remove it. I am using the Java Regex engine.

Edit: 
This is what I have tried:

```
/(#.*\n)/g
```

Comment: try      `^#.*\n` ..................

Comment: did you want to remove the commented line?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes that's what I want. And your regex doesn't work, it doens't match the pound symbol.

Comment: Think you do want to remove the last commented line.

Comment: Use anchors: `^#.*\n$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all the commented lines completely along with their newline character (if exists).

```
string.replaceAll("(?m)^#.*\n?", "");
```

Without the optional quantifier `?`, this `(?m)^#.*\n` regex won't remove the last commented line.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dM0wU5/1)

Comment: This doesn't work in Java, you used the PHP Regex flavor for the demo link.

Comment: @opiop65 did you try that? This should work. Few regexes only differ.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(?m)^#.*\n` as a pattern:

```
String lines = 
    "#This is some text \n" +
    "#This is some text \n" +
    "This is some text I don't want to match\n";
String comment_removed = lines.replaceAll("(?m)^#.*\n", "");
```

Used [`(?m)` (multiline mode)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) to make `^` match at the beginning of the lines. Otherwise, it will match only at the beginning of the string.

[Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/n5Nkqx)